# Javascript / Jquery - Calculate date and time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

Given 
departing date time 13/6/2014 01:00 AM 
and 
estimated landing time is 1 hour 50 minutes

i want the result like: 13/6/2014 2:50 AM

anyone have idea?

i have been using datejs with no luck

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the [datejs tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).  Then take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  Also, you need to consider time zones - else you will possibly have daylight saving time issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, take a look at moment.js (http://momentjs.com)

So let's say you have your starting time and duration set up like this:

```
var departTime = '13/06/2014 01:00 AM';
var duration = '1 hour 50 minutes';
```

First you need to convert the depart time to a moment object and parse the duration, like so:

```
var departTimeObj = moment(departTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
var durationParts = duration.split(' ');
var durationHours = durationParts[0];
var durationMinutes = durationParts[2];
```

Now you can use moment to do the addition:

```
var landingTime = departTimeObj.add({
    hours: durationHours,
    minutes: durationMinutes
});
```

To format the output the way you want, do this:

```
var landingTimeStr = landingTime.format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
var travelling = 110 // in minutes

var departing = new Date(2014, 6, 13, 1, 0, 0, 0);

var arriving = new Date(departing.getTime() + travelling * 60000);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7bVd/).

Or use many of the libraries already out there.

As Matt Johnson says, you need to be weary of *gotchas* like daylight saving time if you're going to be adding variable units of time like *days*.